# how can we use will_paginate in ruby on rails 3.0.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

is their will_paginate will support to ruby on rails 3.0.3?

Answer (score 3):

Yes. In beta - https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/tree/rails3.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Its still in beta and we have used will paginate successfully in a production rails project.The bug that i have seen so far is the count of items at times is wrong. You can work around it by firing your own count query and populate it.